# Can I set up nginx to implement SSI-like functionality?

Tags: nginx

All my pages have similar static `header` and `footer` parts inside the `body` tag. `head` tags are similar too, but feature `title`, `keywords` and `description` which differ between pages.

Can I use `nginx` to compose the output file taking parts of it from static files and other parts from the application server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a module for Nginx to enable SSI functionality.  It's quite [well documented here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSsiModule). There are a few issues to be aware of:

- Relative parent paths are unavailable (e.g., `../..` will not work).
- Some variables (such as `LAST_MODIFIED`) are not available.
- The syntax for directives must include a space (e.g., `<--#include` must be `<--# include`).